# Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined at EditQuestionDialogComponent_Template

Tags: typescript, angular

Проект на Angular
Имеется строковая переменная question, определенная в классе:

```
export class QuestionModel {
  id: string;
  question: string;

  constructor(id: string, question: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.question = question;
  }
}
```

в html файле пред тем как очистить поле делаю проверку, что эта переменная не пустая

```
<button
  *ngIf="quest.question.trim().length > 0"
  class="clear-icon"
  mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
  (click)="question= ''"
>
```

В консоле браузера получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined at EditQuestionDialogComponent_Template
```

Что не так?

Comment: Укажите начальное значение переменной `question: string = ''`

Comment: она инициализируется сразу в конструкторе, т.е. при создании формы она не пустая, я исправил текст вопроса.

Comment: Ну а чем является переменная question? Строкой или экземпляром класса QuestionModel?

Comment: Экземпляром, конечно. Хотел упростить код для вопроса вот и ошибка, исправил в Html